# Android studio 3.0 Canary 4 throwing error while building Instant Apps

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-studio-3.0

I am working on Android Instant App. When i updated AS3.0 to Canary 4, i started getting following error while running project:

Error while Uploading and registering Instant App

**Side loading failed with message: Reading bundle timed out. Do you want to retry?**

Did anyone face this issue? Not sure how to fix this.

**Note:** Gradle version : gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip

**Edit :** Here is log details

> Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.instantapps.devman.iapk.LOAD
>   cmp=com.google.android.instantapps.devman/.iapk.IapkLoadService (has
>   extras) } U=0: not found
>
> Permission Denial: Accessing service
>   ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.instantapps.routing.DomainFilterUpdateService}
>   from pid=3676, uid=2000 that is not exported from uid 10012

Comment: Have you tried disabling AAPT2? Go to your gradle.properties file: android.enableAapt2 = false Hope it works.

Comment: Tried, not working.

Comment: Try to clear instant app on device's Settings -> Apps and Notifications -> App Info -> Your Instant App -> Clear app.

Comment: Please take a look at :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953102/6668797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Android O if possible, I am not good at English, but I will try my best to tell you why I think so.

I use the same develop environment as you (android studio 3.0 preview 4 and gradle-4.0-rc-1, and run android O on my nexus 6p), I still can develop instant app yesterday, but now I meet the same error as you.(yesterday night my phone begin crash, so I flash android 7.1.2 into my phone.)

Comment: Thanks. Working now. But i wondered that how am i able to test instant app without adding google account and allowing Instant app feature on emulator API 26.