# Android Instant Apps not running on Pixel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

Recently my Pixel started showing the following message:

```
Development Mode Active -                           
URLs will be routed to Dev Manager in order to launch Instant Apps locally.
```

Also, in `settings -> apps` I can see Google play services for Instant apps.
Now, when I tried **wish** and **buzzfeed tasty** so that I can run their Instant apps I was taken to their site and not in the Instant app.

I built an Instant app in **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4**.
It is working fine on the emulator but when I connected my **Pixel** running on android 7 it shows the following error -

**Side loading instant app failed: Reading bundle timed out.**

and when I retry some more times it shows this -

```
Side loading instant app failed: Failure when trying to read bundle. 
Unable to connect to Google Play Service ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
```

A same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908139/side-loading-instant-app-failed-reading-bundle-timed-out) **but** in this case the problem is with the emulator not a real device.

***CompiledSdkVersion  25***  
  ***targetSdkVersion  25***  
***buildToolsVersion   25.0.3***

Any help would be appreciated and also a list of some already published instant apps I can try.

Comment: Quick clarification: which country are you in?

Comment: I m from India.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Instant Apps is not yet available in India. That means, Instant Apps features are by default turned off on the real devices, including in development environment. See the list of supported countries here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861#production

We are working on this issue and will provide an update in a few weeks. In the mean time, please use emulators for you development.

Answer (score 0):

In your instant App run configuration.
Try To enable Instant APP Provision and "Clear Provisioned Devices Cache"

[image]

Comment: Instant App Provision was already enabled. But in Provision Specifications, it's only showing Clear cache. After enabling that, now I am seeing only the second error : unable to connect to google play services.

Comment: I do not think this is the cause but check also under settings --> Google --> Instant App

Comment: Google --> Instant App will occur when I will run an Instant app on my phone for the first time. And I searched for some Instant apps already in the market, as I have already mentioned. Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Non, It should be there. If you do not have it, it means your Google play services are not up to date

Comment: Google --> Instant App is not there and I checked for any updates on Google play services but it's showing up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Now Instant apps is available in India.
You can check by searching buzzfeed tasty in chrome.
Attaching screenshot below 
[image]

Or you could visit https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html and click the screenshot on that site. Post clicking website will open. Below that website a popup will show to "open app". Post clicking "open app", instant app will get opened

Note : Turn on instant app in **Google** menu in **Settings** in phone before trying above