# Camera Permission always denied without dialog shown on Google Pixel when running instant app

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-studio-3.0, android-instant-apps, google-pixel

I am porting an existing application to an **instant app** that requires a camera permission to run. On *Pixel 2* device and *Samsung S8* the permission dialogue gets shown and I can request the permission. On the Pixel 1 Device the dialogue does not get shown and the Permission grant result is immediately `returning -1` in `onActivityResult`.

All of the devices run *Android 8.0.0*

I tried a full grandle sync, clean, deleting the instant app, installing the full version and deinstalling it, completely removing the instant app support for the device and re-enabling it, restarting the device, invalidating Android Studios cache and add the clear the cache flags to the run configuration as described here [Android Instant Apps not running on Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948961/android-instant-apps-not-running-on-pixel) .

If I access the permission settings by category, the application is listed, with the camera permission set to off. If I grant the permission there, and return to the screen the camera permission is again disabled. In the application details the instant app is shown as that it does not require any permissions.

*Are the permission settings for instant apps cached in some location on the device ? How can I purge that cache ?*

Comment: App-> your app -> storage -> Clear Data + Clear Cache

Comment: @till-krempel, can have look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66942980 reported bug,Camera implementation still needs work, so you may have to hold off on developing this feature for their instant app for now.

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Clearing Data and Cache did help in any way. Situation is the same after that.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest Android 8.0.0 security update on the Pixel phone resolved the issue. Permissions were asked again.